# Powerbuilder, Composite datawindow, whenever scrolling the report i am getting the Page number popup on the screen

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder

Powerbuilder, Composite datawindow, whenever scrolling the report i am getting the Page number(Page 1, Page 2 ..) popup on the screen. How can we avoid this pop up ?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it might help if you provide more detail. What version of PowerBuilder and is it .NET or Classic?

Comment: Hi I am using the Powerbuilder 12.0 version. Classic.

Comment: Can any one help on this post ?

Comment: Are you using print preview or just retrieving the datawindow on a window and then scrolling?

Comment: just retrieving the datawindow on a window and then scrolling(in Front End at Run time)

Comment: Can any one help please

Comment: Can any one answer on my post please..

Comment: Can any one answer on my post please